# Changing the format of a DateTime field when inserting into SQL Server database using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following `SqlCommand` that inserts a row of data to a SQL Server database table. In particular, the `Value` column is of datatype `DateTime`.

When the command is ran, the date format is:

```
Sep 11 2003 12:00AM
```

Data when viewing in SQL Server database

[image: Data when viewing in SQL database]

However, it needs to be 2003-10-11

When I view it in an application, the date column is blank, but when I change the data directly in the database to match `yyyy-mm-dd`, the column value is visible in the application.

How do I change the format of the date?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(newConnStr))
{
    connection.Open();

    string dateOfInterviewQS =
           "INSERT INTO PropertyValues(PropertyId, UserId, Value, FriendlyName, LastUpdated, CheckDate) " + 
           " VALUES(@PropertyId, " + "@UserId, " + "@Value, " +
                    "@FriendlyName, " + "@LastUpdated, " + "@CheckDate)";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(dateOfInterviewQS, connection))
    {
        SqlParameter date = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        date.Value = DateOfInterview;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyId", 2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendlyName", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdated", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckDate", DateTime.Now);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: A DateTime has no format. A datetime converted to a string has a format. So the problem is more in viewing the datetime somewhere not how its stored in the database.

Comment: Are you referring to the `DateTime.Now` values?  Are the SQL columns also `DATETIME`?  If so, it's not clear what the problem is.  Is the value being inserted incorrect in some way?  Is there an error?  Where/how are you observing this "format"?

Comment: Also, obligatory... [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)  Which may be the root of the problem you're observing, if you're relying on `AddWithValue` to infer data types rather than explicitly specifying them yourself.

Comment: The parameter type is `SqlDbType.DateTime`. You can change it to `SqlDbType.Date`, but do not pass in a `string`. It's supposed to be a `datetime`, which has no format, it's a binary value

Comment: I have added some more info in the original post

Comment: Look for the settings in the tool you provided the screenshot for how the date looks. It should have a setting for this or the settings of your OS are used.

Comment: What you are seeing is **NOT** the format used in the database. It's just a convenience shown to you by your query tool. The actual format in the database is **binary**, and _not human-readable_. If you later need to see the data in a certain format, worry about that at query time. Unless, you actually have a `varchar` column, in which case you have a [broken schema design](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/)

Comment: @dynmatt: *"Data when viewing in SQL database"* - So you're viewing some **output** of the value?  Then that output is where you'd specify a format.  If this is in an application you can specify a `DateTime` format with `ToString`.  Though it looks like this is in something like SSMS, which would involve you updating culture settings somewhere to format the value when displaying it.  In any event, the "problem" you're describing isn't a problem at all.  If the column is a `DATETIME` then you have a valid value.  You can format that value however you want to when you use it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, it is a VARCHAR column, I forgot that! But for good reason. This is the value stored in a custom form builder. The user can create custom forms, it may be a textbox, date picker, bool etc but the value is stored as a varchar

Comment: @dynmatt: Putting aside for a moment that storing a date/time value *as a string* is a bad idea... The concept is still the same.  The only difference now is that you want to format the string before inserting it into the database, because the database is (incorrectly) your "display" of that value.  `DateTime.Now` has no format.  But `DateTime.Now.ToString("some format string")` does.

Comment: That's **NOT** a good reason :( The form builder needs to be smart enough to know to use a date column if the user added a datepicker to the field on the front end. Otherwise, you're stuck with an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) anti-pattern for the schema.

Comment: Good reason? Then tell me how do you think to explain to the database why the string "January 1st 2022" is lesser than "February 2nd 2022" when you need to execute a query on that varchar field or just want to see a set of records ordered by that "date"

Comment: I'm created custom form builders before, you still need to store the data in the correct datatype else you'll be running into issues like this for the life of the product.

Comment: The only reason to store a DateTime as a varchar is if it is outside of your control (ie. existing code base you can't change, source code not in your control, your manager directs you to do it, etc). Using a form builder is not an excuse. Any form builders out there worth its salt can handle date objects. If it is a home grown builder than add support or add a translation layer just as long as you do not persist the date as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things fundamentally wrong here...

1. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
2. Storing a `DateTime` value *as a string* is a bad idea.  Store data *as data*.  Then format it for display when you need to display it.  A `DateTime` is natively understood by the system, easily sortable, can be used to perform date calculations, etc.  A string is just text.  (The format you have is *coincidentally* sortable, but deliberate management of data is always better than something that coincidentally works.)

Having said that...

You can use `.ToString()` to format your `DateTime`.  For example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdated", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Or, if you want single-digit months/days:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdated", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d"));
```

Basically, since you're storing a string, you need to send the database *a string*.  Not a `DateTime`.

(But, again, you *should* be storing a `DateTime` and formatting it as a string when using it downstream.)